# How do I check return a value of this object using Linq

Tags: asp.net, linq

I have 2 related classes:

```
public class BankHolidayColl
{
     public List<BankHoliday> BankHoliday { get; set; }
}

public class BankHoliday
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

I've removed some of the attributes, however this object built from an xml file, like this:

```
var bankHoliday = GetBankHolidaysFromXml();
```

The property bankHoliday.BankHoliday gives me access to a list of names and dates (the names being names of bank holidays).

By providing a date, I want to check if the list contains the date and if so return the name. I've been trying to get the right combination for sometime without any success.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx), for example:

```
public class BankHolidayColl
{
    public List<BankHoliday> BankHoliday { get; set; }

    public BankHoliday GetBankHoliday(DateTime date)
    {
        if (BankHoliday == null || BankHoliday.Count == 0)
            return null;
        return BankHoliday.FirstOrDefault(h => h.Date.Date == date.Date);
    }
}
```

Then you get `null` or the first instance of `BankHoliday` with a given date:

```
BankHoliday bh = myBankHolidayColl.GetBankHoliday(DateTime.Now);
if(bh != null)
{
    string bhName = bh.Name;
}
```

If you insist on a method which returns only the name, add this:

```
public string GetBankHolidayName(DateTime date)
{
    if (BankHoliday == null || BankHoliday.Count == 0)
        return null;
    return BankHoliday.Where(h => h.Date.Date == date.Date)
                      .Select(h => h.Name)
                      .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Where** to filter by you date, then **Select** to get only yor name, the **FirstOrDefault**, which will return null if there is no such value, or first name of holiday, if such exists

```
var result = BankHoliday
.Where(hol => hol.Date == youDate)
.Select(hot => new { hol.Name })
.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var _result = BankHolidayColl.Where(x => x.Date == youDate)
                            .Select(x => new {Name=x.Name})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
BankHoliday.Where(b => b.Date == someDate).Select(b => b.Name)
```